# Updating dictionary using a function that adds other value from a list

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

```
function = ({"Books":10,"pens":20},[("Books",-5),("pens",-11),("pencils",3)])
```

Goal: update the dictionary to output: {"Books":5,"pens":9,"pencils":3}

```
for key,value in dicto.items():
        for item in mylist:
            if key == item[0]:
                dict[key] += item[1]
```

Why does my output not include the pencils key?

Comment: what is 'mylist '? where is 'dict ' in your outer loop defined? show all your relevant code.

Comment: mylist = [("Books",-5),("pens",-11),("pencils",3)] and dicto = {"Books":10,"pens":20}

Comment: don't use `dict` as a variable name if hides Python's `dict` type. You don't have `pencils` in the original dictionary so you can't `+=`. You could use: `dict[key] = dict.get(key, 0) + item[1]` to ensure the key is added.

Comment: Can you use the `Counter` from `collections`?

Comment: Not really, I prefer not to!

Answer (score 3):

You are iterating over just the keys in the original dict, so `key` is never equal to pencils. You should instead iterate over the keys that are given in the list

```
>>> def f(D, L):
...     for k, v in L:
...         D[k] = D.get(k, 0) + v
...     return D
... 
>>> f({"Books":10,"pens":20},[("Books",-5),("pens",-11),("pencils",3)])
{'pencils': 3, 'Books': 5, 'pens': 9}
```

Aside:

The `Counter` class is ideal for this type of thing

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> def f(D, L):
...     return Counter(D) + Counter(dict(L))
... 
>>> f({"Books":10,"pens":20},[("Books",-5),("pens",-11),("pencils",3)])
Counter({'pens': 9, 'Books': 5, 'pencils': 3})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for key, value in mylist:
    dict[key] = dict.get(key, 0) + value
```

inspired by AChampion